# Media query not found in my style section

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css, razor, media-queries

Do I have to add some link or file to get media queries to work. When I try to use a media query inline in a .cshtml file I get a red line under '@media' that says "cannot resolve symbol media". This is in a asp.net mvc project. When I move the media query to it's own .css file it works fine. Are media queries not allowed inline in a asp mvc project?

[image]

Comment: please give us total codes not one incomplete image. [html,css]

Comment: What browser are you even using? _What_ says “cannot resolve symbol `media`”?

Comment: IE 11. Yes when I hover over '@media' it says 'cannot resolve symbol', do I need to add a reference or something to use media queries??

Comment: possible duplicate of [@media media query and ASP.NET MVC razor syntax clash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027469/media-media-query-and-asp-net-mvc-razor-syntax-clash)

Answer (score 4):

Here is what solved it.

```css
 @@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
   /* only size 'xs' and below */
   .searchResults {
     height: 100%;
   }
```

I added two @ symbols.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by putting the media query into a .css file. When it was inline in the .cshtml file it didn't work. Code below

```css
<style> 
html,body,.container-fluid,.row {
  height: 100%;
}
.row > div {
  height: 100%;
}
.row .col-md-5 {
  background-color: #eee;
  top: 51px;
  /*border: 1px solid black;*/
  height: calc(100% - 51px);
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
.row .col-md-7 {
  background-color: #ddd;
  top: 51px;
  /*border: 1px solid black;*/
  height: calc(100% - 51px);
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
#googleResultMap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /*border: 1px solid black;*/
}
.searchFilter {
  /*width:200px;*/
  height: 20%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.searchResults {
  height: 80%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  overflow-y: scroll
}
input[readonly].default-cursor {
  cursor: default;
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) { // does not work
/* only size 'xs' and below */
.searchResults {
    height: 100%;
}
}
</style> 
<link href="~/Content/MediaQueries.css" rel="stylesheet" /> //works
```

Answer (score -1):

What you have done is that you not specified the media rule

your code should be something like

```
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) { ... }
```

**Edited:**

At the top of your webpage add this line of the code in the `<head>` tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, scale=1.0" />
```

Then in the style defination:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) { 
.searchFilter {
 height:100%;
              }
     }
```

Comment: NO! maybe I didn't explain my question correctly. VS can't find this symbol? SO when I run it in IE I get this error message The name 'media' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Oh that seems to be browser specific error, it runs fine in other browsers right?

Comment: I currently have "<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">" in my head tag

Comment: does this code run fine in other browsers except IE?

Comment: No, this isn't a browser specific error. This error is coming from the IIS, not the browser. And no, it doesn't work in any other browsers.

Comment: can you post your full code so that i can debug it? And does that error come on your console of the browser? Also make sure that you write the code before you include other plugins like bootstrap in your code

Comment: one thing I just noticed is that the media query doesn't throw any errors when I have it in a .css file. If I put it inline with my html in the styles section tag like shown above it doesn't like it. When you say full code, which parts do you want? the html and css page?

Comment: The full code of the screenshot that you have put in the question. Check if you have defined the `<style>` tags correctly.

Comment: I'll post a solution below. It might not be the correct one but it's how I got it to work. I put the media query into a .css file